# java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException when closing ZipFileSystem

Tags: java, zip, nio

I am randomly getting the following error when closing my ZipFileSystem:

```
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.ensureOpen(FileChannelImpl.java:109)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:275)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:49)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.readFullyAt(ZipFileSystem.java:952)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.readFullyAt(ZipFileSystem.java:945)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.copyLOCEntry(ZipFileSystem.java:1155)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.sync(ZipFileSystem.java:1259)
[16:59:27] [Thread-1/INFO] [STDERR]: [com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync:1262]:   at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.close(ZipFileSystem.java:277)
```

This is not an exception, but rather a message which gets printed from `com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem:sync` many times (once for each file). I can't figure out what's going on, and which channels the `ClosedChannelException` is referring to. The files don't get saved to the ZipFileSystem when this happens.

Here's how I'm creating my ZipFileSystem:

```
Map<String, String> env = new HashMap<>();
env.put("create", "true");
URI classCachesURI = classCachesZip.toURI();
URI classCachesZipURI = new URI("jar:" + classCachesURI.getScheme(), classCachesURI.getPath(), null);
cacheFileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(classCachesZipURI, env, null);
```

writing to it:

```
Files.write(cacheFileSystem.getPath(name), data);
```

and closing it:

```
cacheFileSystem.close();
```

I looked at the documentation many times and I can't see what I could be doing wrong. What should I be doing to avoid this problem?

Comment: Works for me. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Creating the FileSystem, writing a few files to it with the code above, and then closing it causes that issue randomly (around 1/10 times).